# Using join and pivot in entity framework with C# or write a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I want to create a custom joined table and want to show rows to the columns. 
I want to get Invitation informations that are default but joined with the question answers that people give to any invitation.

I need question and answer rows to the columns. (I think we should use pivot but i am not sure.)

I couldnt able to find a way to do this in ef c# using lambda or linq. Or I'm using sql server 2012, so if you give me the sql statement for this purpose, i will be really appreciated.

Here are my tables.

People

```
id | name       | surname  
---+------------+------------
 1 |    carl    | sagan  
 2 |    john    | wick   
 3 |    alex    | rony   
 4 |    mary    | olsen
```

Invitation

```
 id | name       | peopleid  | hasquestion | isdefault  
---+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------
 1 |    inv1     | 1         |    0        |    1
 2 |    inv2     | 1         |    1        |    0
 3 |    inv3     | 2         |    0        |    0
 4 |    inv4     | 2         |    1        |    1
 5 |    inv5     | 2         |    1        |    0
 6 |    inv6     | 3         |    1        |    1
 7 |    inv7     | 4         |    0        |    1
```

Question

```
 id | text         
---+------------
 1 |    question 1    
 2 |    question 2       
 3 |    question 3        
 4 |    question 4
 5 |    question 5
```

QuestionAnswers

```
id | invitationid | questionid  | answer
---+--------------+-------------+--------
 1 |    2         | 1           |    abc
 2 |    2         | 2           |    def
 3 |    2         | 3           |    ghi
 4 |    4         | 3           |    jkl
 5 |    4         | 4           |    mno
 6 |    5         | 1           |    prs    
 7 |    6         | 5           |    tuy
```

My result table should be:

```
id |  peoplename     | default   | question 1  | question 2 | question 3 | question 4 | question 5  
---+-----------------+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
 1 |    carl sagan   | inv1      |    abc      |    def     |   ghi      |            |   
 2 |    john wick    | inv4      |    prs      |            |   jkl      |    mno     |   
 3 |    alex rony    | inv6      |             |            |            |            |    tuy
 3 |    mary olsen   | inv7      |             |            |            |            |
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is easily achievable via LINQ. If it is achievable, I can only imagine a quite complex lambda. Would it not be better in terms of perfomance and code readability to write a stored procedure, and simply call the procedure from EF?

Comment: If it will be very complex lambda, i can use a stored procedure, but i need that procedure too, cause i couldnt able to write sql statement for this problem.

Comment: See my SQL in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can run this script to create your SQL procedure first.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_question_answers
AS
SELECT 
[peoplename],
[invitation],
[question 1],
[question 2],
[question 3],
[question 4],
[question 5]
FROM 
(SELECT 
p.[name] + ' ' + p.surname AS [peoplename],
i.[name] AS invitation,
q.[text] question,
qa.answer
 FROM dbo.people p  
 INNER JOIN dbo.invitations i ON p.id = i.people_id
 INNER JOIN dbo.question_answers qa ON i.id = qa.invitation_id
 LEFT JOIN dbo.questions q ON qa.question_id = q.id)
 AS SourceTable
 PIVOT 
 (
 MAX(answer)
 FOR question  IN 
([question 1],
[question 2],
[question 3],
[question 4],
[question 5]) 
)AS PivotTable;
GO
```

Then you can execute procedure via entity framework. `IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> answers = dbContext.FromSql<QuestionAnswer>("Exec sp_get_question_answers");`

Assuming `QuestionAnswer` is a class that has properties matching those returned from the procedure.

Comment: Thank you but question table is not fixed , i mean there can be many questions and the number of question can be more than 5. The lenght is unknown

Comment: with pivot tables u have to 'hard code' columns. It is usually useful when the expected results fall within a known finite range. But for your case im thinking it might not be the best idea, coz if u get to lets say 100 questions, it becomes a bit messy as well. Maybe can u shed a bit more light on your actual problem, there could be another way of solving it.